# Stop weapon from clipping into planes using URP Unity 2020.1.5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey so i am currently making a 3D game that involves slicing things with a katana. But whenever i get close to it my weapon goes right through it.

---

I knew how to use the old version of doing it with the clipping mask and the second camera but using the URP i can't find anything related to it.

---

Thanks in advance i am really struggling here.

---

Here you can see my sword model clipping through the orange cube.

[image]

Comment: Usually the solution is to use one camera the renders the weapon and nothing else, and underneath that have a camera that renders everything else; this way the weapons will never clip

Comment: @Ron yes i actually knew you could do that but i cant find the options in the urp rendering pipeline

Comment: Too long for comments; Posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this sample scene in URP:
[image]

Use two cameras with the same perspective/position/rotation/etc:

1. Camera rendering *nothing but* the `Weapon` Layer (Weapon cam)
2. Camera rendering *everything but* the `Weapon` layer (World cam)
3. Set weapon cam to overlay
   [image]
4. Add weapon cam as stacked camera on world camera
   [image]

How it with 1 camera:

[image]

And with it:

[image]